# How to load Northwind into SQLite3 -- Error 'File is not a database'

Tags: sqlite, northwind

I am trying to load the Northwind.Sqlite3.create.sql hosted on https://github.com/jpwhite3/northwind-SQLite3 into SQLite3 on Ubuntu.

I have tried using: `sqlite3 Northwind.Sqlite3.create.sql` to import the database. 
However when I try to view the data using `SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;` I get an error saying `Error: file is not a database`

Any suggestions as to how to open the database file and use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a text file full of DDL statements, not a sqlite3 database. You'd have to import it into a database with something like

```
sqlite3 mydatabase.db < Northwind.Sqlite3.create.sql
```